# kotlin spring boot 3 - cannot resolve spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.0

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-boot-starter

I'm getting a weird resolution error when trying to upgrade to spring boot 3. I have a kotlin/spring project. The only thing sort of related is [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6766), but it's not the same dependency.

Here's the error:
`Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.0.`

Here's my dependency declaration:

```
plugins {
        id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0' // latest at this time
        id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.0'
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa' version '1.7.10'
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring' version '1.7.10'
}
```

Here's my full output:

[image: full dependency output]

What I've tried:

- Switching to Java 17
- Searching online for the same exact error - no luck so far. (11-29-2022 10AM ET)

Comment: Judging by the error message, your attempt to switch to Java 17 wasn't successful. Gradle is running on Java 11 (it's the consumer in the context of the error) and Spring Boot 3.0 requires Java 17.

Answer (score 2):

Modify the Gradle JVM in the settings
[image]